# Nullable one-hot encoding

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Can I have a one-hot encoding like `[none, 1, 0, 0, none]`;
i.e. I don't know if the sample class is `0` or `4`, but I know its class `1`, but not class `2` or `3`

The loss function would then ignore where there's a `none` so we don't provide false-negatives.

Answer (score 0):

The original case has categories: 0,1,2,3,4. To solve your question you can create the categories as follows:

- 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
- where the 5th category represents unsure nature of label, that is, its value will be 1 if you are unsure about the data point belonging to 0 or 4th label.

Now you will have one-hot encoding in the form of [0,0,0,0,0,1] for the data points where it might belong to 0th or 4th category. You can filter these rows out and perform training on the remaining rows.

Comment: This is nto the same thing, essentially my samples are not exclusive one category, and sometimes I don't know which categories it is hot for. I want the network to learn them, but I also want to train the network on the categories I'm sure about

Comment: If I used this sort of technique, I would get a y vector of size n factorial (to account for all the combinations of nulls)

Comment: So you are saying that adding a 5th category = `unknown/none` to any data point for which we are unsure of the label will not help? And could you explain how does adding one column increase the y vector size to n factorial?

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/27251/machine-learning-classification-confidence more info